# Can't see tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've created a schema in my PostgreSQL database that Hibernate uses, creating tables, persisting entities and so on. After I updated my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, I can't see the tables anymore. The applications that manipulate data in the schema and its tables can still do it, though.

Here is the output of some commands after I login using `sudo -u postgres psql`:

```
postgres=# \dt
No relations found.
postgres=# \dn
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   
--------+----------
 jcat   | postgres
 public | postgres
(2 rows)

postgres=# \dn+
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description       
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 jcat   | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| 
        |          | =UC/postgres         | 
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | =UC/postgres         | 
(2 rows)
```

I've tried the following, from a few questions I aswers I found:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA jcat TO public;
grant ALL on SCHEMA jcat to public;
```

but I still can't see my tables. Any hints?

**Edit:** here are the information requested.

```
postgres-# \d jcat.*
Did not find any relation named "jcat.*".
postgres-# show search_path
postgres-#
```

Comment: What does `show search_path` give you?  What does `\d jcat.*` give you?

Comment: I just added it to the question.

Comment: You need to end SQL statements with a `;`. Your `show search_path` did not actually run. But if `\d jcat.*` results in "did not find any relation" it means there are not tables in that schema. What do you get if you run `select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'jcat';`

Comment: `show search_path;` shows 1 row: `"$user", public`. The select statement you just requested returns 0 rows.

Comment: Then there are no tables in the `jcat` schema.

Comment: Can I be logging in the wrong way? For example, in my local machine, my application authenticates itself using a username and password, but through `psql` I use `sudo` and type no password at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113401/discussion-between-douglas-de-rizzo-meneghetti-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are manually connecting to a different database than your ORM or code is connecting to (or at least I was running into the same problem as you and it turns out that's what I was doing).

It can help clear up a lot of confusion if you use a good GUI tool to look around in your database to help you figure out where your tables are actually ending up.  PGAdmin4 was my tool of choice, might be worth a shot: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/

You can also try setting your search path from the command line when connecting via psql.  On Ubuntu that looks like this:

```
PGOPTIONS='-c search_path=jcat' psql -h your.host -U youruser
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I was running Postgresql 12 in a docker container and using volume with data. When accessing the database to show a list of tables, an error occurred:

```
"ERROR: column c.relhasoids does not exist at character 190".
```

Data for DB was from Postgresql 11.
When I rebuilt the dockerfile with image Postgresql 11 everything was OK